# ReactJS undefined useState fileContent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, react-hooks, papaparse

I am uploading a local csv file from my computer. Then I am storing the content of this csv file into a useState (setFileContent). When I console.log the content of this file right before the line setFileContent(contentObj), I get a nice array of objects just like I want. However, in the finally, when I console.log the useState fileContent I get undefined and it is also saying in my  that fileContent is undefined and it is not possible to apply map on undefined. Why is contentObj not stored in the useState file content ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [fileContent, setFileContent] = useState()
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState()

  const handleOnChange = (f) => {
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const files = f.target.files;
      setFilename(files["0"].name)
      if (files) {
        Papa.parse(files[0], {
          complete: function (results) {
            let content = results.data.slice(1)
            let contentObj = content.map(c => ({
              "ID": c[0],
              "name": c[1],
              "lastname": c[2],
              "age": c[3],
              "address": c[4],
              "radius": c[5],
              "lat": c[6],
              "long": c[7],
            }))

            console.log(contentObj)
            setFileContent(contentObj)

          }
        })
      }

    } catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  };


  // function to calculate the middle points 
  var location = [15.47, 115.10]

  return (

    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <Button variant="contained" component="label">
          Upload a File
          <input hidden accept=".csv" multiple type="file" onChange={handleOnChange} />
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10, color: "white" }}>

        {filename}

      </div>

      <Grid container spacing={2}>

        <Grid xs={1}></Grid>
        <Grid xs={10}>
          <Card
            style={{
              borderRadius: 10,
              height: 600,
              overflowX: "none",
              overflowY: 'auto',
              marginBottom: 1000,
              marginTop: 20
            }}
            variant='outlined'
          >

            {loading ? <CircularProgress /> : <div>
              <MapContainer center={location} zoom={6} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                <TileLayer
                  url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
                />
                {fileContent && fileContent.map(e => (
                  <Circle
                    center={[e.latitude_deg, e.longitude_deg]}
                    pathOptions={{ color: 'red' }}
                    radius={e.accuracy_level == "HIGH" ? 5000 : e.accuracy_level == "MEDIUM" ? 15000 : 30000}>
                  </Circle>


                ))}

              </MapContainer>
            </div>}
            
          </Card>

        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={1}></Grid>

      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just to double check, have you imported `useState` somewhere in you code?

Comment: @node_modules  I don't believe he/she means `React.useState` is undefined, but that the `fileContent` is undefined, the title is maybe a tad missleading.

Comment: It looks like `Papa.parse` is async, this means your setting `isLoading` before it's loaded..

Comment: Thank you @Keith, what should I change to avoid that?

Comment: First, you can get rid of the `isLoading`, just change your check from `{loading ? ` to -> `{!fileContent ?`,  you can then also remove `fileContent &&` as it can then never be undefined.  Your `setFileContent(` will then cause a re-render with loaded data.

Comment: I changed what you asked me but if I try to console.log(fileContent) in finally I get undefined and also Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in my MapContainer ...  This is what I changed : {!fileContent && !filename ? <CircularProgress /> : <div>
              <MapContainer center={location} zoom={6} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                <TileLayer/>
                {fileContent.map(e => (
                  <Circle

Comment: Yes, it won't be in the `finally`,  but `!fileContent && !filename` is saying if there is no fileContent and there is no filename, you really want  or `||` here, otherwise if `filename` is set before `fileContent` then it's going to be `undefined`,..

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `setFileContent` is asynchronous function, so You need to use `useEffect` hook to achieve `fileContent`

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(fileContent);
}, [fileContent]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a `useEffect` that is already coming from an event, it's already an effect that's going to trigger a state change.  If a state/props change could trigger some other effect, eg. loading data, that's when you want to use it.